# Microclover Mix Lawns

Tags: lawn, grass, variety-selection, clover

What has been people's experience with microclover/grass mix lawns? In theory they sound incredible, but I'm afraid that the clover will be so hearty that it will take over the entire lawn.

Here's an example: http://protimelawnseed.com/collections/sports/products/rough-ready-eco-turf

I have a large dog, three young kids, and a 4,000 sq ft backyard. I want something that can deal with the punishment, keeps the weeds away, and is easily maintained. It doesn't have to look as nice as the front yard.

Comment: Hi! Do you have rabbits? Do you like rabbits? I have no experience with this lawn mix, although it looks very pretty. My bunnies love clover of all kinds, and I love watching them eat it. They do no damage, and actually encourage growth, but if you don't like them, this may not be your best choice. Let us know what happens if you use this, so we can learn!

Comment: My dog loves rabbits! She's usually not fast enough to catch them though. ;)

Comment: I grew up with clover for lawns.  One other caveat are the bees.  Sweet bees LOVE clover.  I wouldn't necessarily go barefoot when the clover is in flower.  If someone in your family is truly allergic to bee/wasp stings.  Not a good idea.  Otherwise, you'll be a hero for feeding bees!  No pesticides.  If you have a problem please come back to ask.  Hey, we kids made clover leis among all the bees a buzzin'.

Answer (score 9):

Microclover (Trifolium repens var.pirouette) is a selection from the original white clover (Trifolium repens). It was bred and selected for its much smaller leaves, lower height, much less aggressive invasive tendencies, non clumping habit and its reluctance to produce flowers; flowering is undesirable in lawn clover, particularly where there are children. In theory, then, it makes a good addition to other lawn grass seeds, because, like all clovers, it fixes nitrogen in its roots, and may well supply the rest of the lawn with nitrogen whilst its present, and tends to mix in with grasses as it grows rather than taking over in some areas, as the original Trifolium repens does.

In practice, I've never used it, so can't comment on how it performs in the field so to speak - more information here http://plantscience.psu.edu/reduce-runoff/questions-about-microclover

Comment: We've used it for all of the reasons advertised. Although the leaves ARE smaller and it produces fewer, lower flowers, it has always grown larger than "advertised." And as @Ecnerwal said it does take over in areas that previously produced poor turf. In theory the clover will improve soil conditions and should promote turf growth, but we haven't had it in place long enough to prove this.

Comment: @ThatIdiot - why not post an answer saying that, since you've got actual experience of using it - I'd give you a vote for sure! But is the one you used actually microclover? Some mixes use mini clover, which isn't so small...

Comment: We've used both. It was difficult to distinguish the mini-clover from regular dutch dwarf which had grown in less than optimal conditions.

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea about "microclover" which sounds like a hokey marketing term, but I have been putting Dutch white clover in lawns for decades and it works just fine, unless you are one of those folks that dumps weedkiller on the lawn (clover is a broadleaf and will be killed by "lawn weedkiller") or thinks that clover IS a weed. The only place that clover "takes over" are the same places grass won't grow at all - the clover is tougher under wear.

Comment: Good point about the broadleaf killer. I didn't think of that. I think I can get by without using weedkiller so long as the clover does it's job by making it harder for weeds to get going in the first place.

Comment: Of course you can get by NEVER using weedkiller.  Check the optimal mowing height.  Check the pH of your soil.  Are you starting with bare ground?  Do get a soil test.  If one understands the crop they are cultivating one can pretty much quit worrying about weeds.  This is similar to cool season grasses so I am thinking mow no LOWER than 3".  Right there weed seeds can't germinate in the shade of 3".  Water DEEPLY, let dry out before watering again to encourage deep roots, weeds have shallow roots and dry out far more quickly.  Mow once per week minimum.  Bag and compost clippings!